# Not getting reputation change notifications after opting for Winter Bash

Tags: bug, reputation, notification-bar

About an hour ago, I opted in for Winter Bash. But after that, I am getting no further reputation notifications (the green ones). I have earned 20 rep on Stack Overflow after that; but got no notification in the top-bar.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fixed now. :)
as of 8:31 AM Tuesday, 15 December 2015. It may have been fixed even earlier.