# Not getting achievement notifications since Winter Bash

Tags: bug, badges, notifications, top-bar

Similar to [Not getting reputation change notifications after opting for Winter Bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270849/not-getting-reputation-change-notifications-after-opting-for-winter-bash), but pertaining to achievement notifications. I've verified that I earned several Bronze badges yesterday (17 December 2015) which have not yet appeared in notification; the last badge that did appear was my Reviewer badge on SO, which I earned just before I opted in to Winter Bash.

I *am* getting reputation-change notifications, so this must be a different bug.

Comment: Review did, but Scholar and Commentator did not. Screen shot as soon as I figure it out.

Comment: No, now  there's no need in the screen  - not a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact the bronze badges like Scholar or Commentator not appearing in the dropdown isn't a bug, but a feature - many bronze badges are considered insignficant (fair enough - do you think Student is a signficant achievement), and not included in the dropdown except the very first time you get them as a complete newbie to the whole SE network.

This doesn't happen with all the bronze badges - the ones like Nice answer/question will be included in the dropdown. As for the silver and gold badges - you always get notified of them.

(Btw - not related to winterbash)

Comment: Ah - wasn't aware of that. Still, even though they may not have been significant to anyone else, no-one else should be getting my notifications anyway... ;) Anyway, thanks for the quick answer.